# How to add titles to multiple OptionMenu's in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

I have the following 3 lists:

```
owner = ['Spain', 'United Kingdom', 'Malaysia']
phase= ['A100', 'B100', 'C100']
machine = ['LLT', 'AAF', 'GGG', 'TGF']
```

With above lists I'm trying to make 3 OptionMenus, this works great. However, when I try to add titles it does not look very neat.

**This is my code:**

```
window = Tk()
window.title("Running Python Script") #Create window
window.geometry('550x300') #geo of the window

def run():
    os.system('python "c:\data\FF\Desktop\PythonFolder\FF_software.py"') 

#The run button (this button runs some other software)
run_button = Button(window, text="Run your Code!", bg="blue", fg="white",command=run)
run_button.grid(column=0, row=0)

#These are the option menus
dd_owner = StringVar(window)
dd_owner.set(owner[0]) #the first value

dd_phase= StringVar(window)
dd_phase.set(phase[0]) 

dd_machine= StringVar(window)
dd_machine.set(machine[0])

w = OptionMenu(window, dd_owner, *owner)
w2 = OptionMenu(window, dd_phase, *phase)
w3 = OptionMenu(window, dd_machine, *machine)

#These are the titles
l1 = Label(window,  text='Select Owner', width=15 )  
l1.grid(row=5,column=1)

l2 = Label(window,  text='Select phase', width=15 )  
l2.grid(row=6,column=1)

l3 = Label(window,  text='Select machine', width=15 )  
l3.grid(row=7,column=1)

w.grid()
w2.grid()
w3.grid()

mainloop()
```

**This is my outcome:**

[image]

As you can see, it does not look very neat. The titles are above the option menus and not beside them from the left.

Comment: Why did you not specify any grid coordinates for the menus?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I totally forgot that, could that solve the problem?

Comment: If you try it you will know.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes it did. Oke thank you, by the way. Is there a way to make my code shorter? Because when I have around 10+optionMenus I just keep copying above snippets of code..

Comment: @TangerCity you can store them in a dictionary and loop iterate through key-value. Take Label text as `dict` key and your option menu values as values for `dict`. Now you can simply loop through them and cut your code short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
w.grid(row=5,column=2)
w2.grid(row=6,column=2)
w3.grid(row=7,column=2)
```

replace last 3 lines with this and you are done.
you can change column value as you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232897/discussion-between-abhishek-aggarwal-and-tangercity).